# Coding4Fun Toolkit not working in windows phone 8.1 and 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I downloaded the toolkit from codeplex.Add all references from the folder.Now when I try to rebuild my solution it gives errors like this

[image]

When I remove the Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Audio it gives this error

[image]

Need help to fix this.

Comment: I think Coding4Fun is not available for windows phone 8.1. there are big changes in 8.1 like universal app and silverlight app.

Comment: Are you building a Silverlight or universal 8.1 app?

Comment: I am building universal app